# How can I use Numpy functions instead of For-loops to access and manipulate adjacent array entries?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, agent-based-modeling

I'm trying to simulate a stochastic system on a 2D grid. Basically, everytime a random clock rings, the color of a pixel changes to some other color, possibly changing the color of some random nearest neighbor too. The following code gives the desired result but not the desired speed (at least for a 1000x1000 grid):

```
import numpy as np
import random as rd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

#define colormap
color= ['aquamarine','cyan','deepskyblue','dodgerblue',
        'fuchsia','mediumorchid','blueviolet','darkslateblue']
cmap=colors.ListedColormap(color)

#define transition rates: 0->1 at rate[0], 1->2 at rate[1], 2->3 at rate [2],
#3->0 at rate[3], 4->5 at rate[4], 5->6 at rate[5], 6->7 at rate[6], 7->4 at rate[7]
rate = np.array([0.21, 1, 1, 1, 0.25, 1, 1, 1])

#set time interval                    
T=100
time =np.arange(T)

#define initial configuration
N=1000
config = np.zeros((N,N), dtype=int)
for i in range(450,550):
    for j in range(450,550):
        config[i][j]=4

#change configuration according to some rule
def step(config, n):
        r = rate[config]                #get only those entries
        k = np.random.poisson(lam=r)    #that are randomly 
        x = np.transpose(np.nonzero(k)) #activated and
        np.random.shuffle(x)            #traverse them in
        for ind in x:                   #random order
            i=ind[0]
            j=ind[1]
            if config[i,j]==3:          #if in state 3
                vec = rd.choice([[-1,0],[1,0],[0,1],[0,-1]])#choose
                x =(i+vec[0])%n         #a random neighbour
                y =(j+vec[1])%n
                config[x,y] = 0         #and send them
                config[i,j] = 0         #to state 0
            elif config[i,j]==7:        #same here, but send them to state 4
                vec = rd.choice([[-1,0],[1,0],[0,1],[0,-1]])
                x =(i+vec[0])%n
                y =(j+vec[1])%n
                config[x,y] = 4
                config[i,j] = 4
            else:
                config[i,j] = config[i,j]+1#othwise move to next state

#set up plot        
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
im=ax.imshow(config[::-1],cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=cmap.N)
time_text=ax.text(2*N/3,N-1,"time="+str(0))

def update(t):
    step(config, N)
    im.set_data(config[::-1])
    time_text.set_text("time="+str((t+1)/T))
    return im, time_text,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=time,
                    interval=5, blit=True, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

(For reference: A 100x100 grid takes roughly 7 seconds, a 500x500 grid 45 s)
I suspect that the `step()` function is rather slow due to looping over a possibly large array.
**Question 1:** (How) can Numpy functions be uitilized to avoid the For-loop?
**Question 2:** Is there any other (easy) option to increase the simulation speed?

At first I thought that `np.where()` could be employed to circumvent the For-loop and its inner If-statement but I don't kow how to access and modify (random) adjacent elements.
Besides that I've tried to use Numba with zero success (but lots of warnings and errors). Is it worth trying to make it work?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you are absolutely correct to seek a vectorised method. However, in this instance, the `if` with **multiple conditions** and `elifs` might make the formation of this complex and therefore hard to implement... so it will be interesting to see an answer.

Comment: So you have to pick on pixel at at time?  Can't do multiple ones at a time?  And then change one other pixel conditionnally?  Further more is it possible that the changes at, say step, 100, will depend on changes made at step 1?  `vectorization` in numpy means working with a whole bunch of changes at once.  Sounds like your problem is inherently sequential.

Comment: @hpaulj Each time `step()` is called, every pixel has a chance to be changed (and maybe its neighbors). This is what I meant by the clock ringing (exponentially distributed inter-arrival times). It is possible that two adjacent pixels are chosen in the same step (possible in discrete time only) and the result depends on the order which is why the array of all chosen pixels is shuffled before looping to avoid systematic bias. So this answers Q1; it's not possible to use Vectorization? What would you suggest instead to improve performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main idea is that most pixels are not 3 or 7, and so their changes can be vectorized. Then we do the neighbor changes from 3's and 7's one by one. For competing influences, we keep track of it in `spread_changes` and then randomly pick one as the one that "applied last." The neighbor influence is definitely the slow step here, but I haven't figured out a good way to vectorize it.

```
import random as rd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

#define colormap
color= ['aquamarine','cyan','deepskyblue','dodgerblue',
        'fuchsia','mediumorchid','blueviolet','darkslateblue']
cmap=colors.ListedColormap(color)

#define transition rates: 0->1 at rate[0], 1->2 at rate[1], 2->3 at rate [2],
#3->0 at rate[3], 4->5 at rate[4], 5->6 at rate[5], 6->7 at rate[6], 7->4 at rate[7]
rate = np.array([0.21, 1, 1, 1, 0.25, 1, 1, 1])

#set time interval                    
T=100
time =np.arange(T)

#define initial configuration
N=1000
config = np.zeros((N,N), dtype=int)
for i in range(450,550):
    for j in range(450,550):
        config[i][j]=4


def step(n):
    global config
    k = np.random.poisson(lam = rate[config])
    change_mask = np.array(k > 0, dtype = 'int')
    three_mask = np.array(config == 3, dtype = 'int')
    seven_mask = np.array(config == 7, dtype = 'int')
    
    plus_one = (config+1)*change_mask*(1-three_mask)*(1-seven_mask)
    no_change = config*(1-change_mask)
    # three_to_zero = three_mask*change_mask*0  #Don't need this, it's always all zeros
    seven_to_four = seven_mask*change_mask*4
    
    config = plus_one + no_change + seven_to_four
    
    
    spread_changes = defaultdict(list)
    
    for y,x in zip(*np.nonzero(seven_mask*change_mask)):
        dy, dx = random.choice([[1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1]])
    
        spread_changes[(y+dy)%N, (x+dx)%N].append(4)
    
    for y,x in zip(*np.nonzero(three_mask*change_mask)):
        dy, dx = random.choice([[1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1]])
    
        spread_changes[(y+dy)%N, (x+dx)%N].append(0)

    for i,j in spread_changes:
  
        choice = random.randint(0, len(spread_changes[i,j]))

        if choice < len(spread_changes[i,j]):

            config[i,j] = spread_changes[i,j][choice]


#set up plot        
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
im=ax.imshow(config[::-1],cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=cmap.N)
time_text=ax.text(2*N/3,N-1,"time="+str(0))

def update(t):
    global config
    step(N)
    im.set_data(config[::-1])
    time_text.set_text("time="+str((t+1)/T))
    return im, time_text,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=time,
                    interval=5, blit=True, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much for this nice solution! It seems that the growth rate of the central red *blob* has decreased compared to the original code. IMHO that's because of its convex shape and in turn a higher chance for blueish cells to be selected. However, this might be closer to the dynamics I actually want to simulate, so I happily accept the answer :)